# TensorFlow Odd Even Binary Padding

Tags: python, tensorflow

Using TensorFlow to build a BNN. I am trying to pad my tensor with interchanging -1 and 1 as seen in FBNA: A Fully Binarized Neural Network Accelerator Figure 3. The next 2D array should have opposite -1, 1 pattern. I can achieve this in a nested for loop but this is very slow.

Can anyone figure out a faster way?

Thanks

Comment: Please post your code here...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have come up with a solution but its probably not very pretty (I am new to TensorFlow). This took a lot of trial and error. Also, it only supports 4D tensors with channel lengths = 1, 3, or any even channel length.

If anyone out there can do a prettier/more versatile version please post, thank.

```
def OddEvenPad(X):

  #create 1D padding tile
  unit_tile = tf.Variable([1., -1.], tf.float32, validate_shape=False)
  unit_tile = tf.reshape(unit_tile, [2,1])
  tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

  #variables
  pad_col_size = int(X.get_shape()[1])
  pad_row_size = int(X.get_shape()[2] + 2)
  num_channels = int(X.get_shape()[3])
  num_batch = int(X.get_shape()[0])

  #tile padding 1D
  pad_col = tf.tile(tf.negative(unit_tile), [int(pad_col_size/2),1])
  pad_row = tf.tile(unit_tile, [int(pad_row_size/2),1])

  if num_channels%2==0:
      #tile padding 2D
      pad_col = tf.concat([pad_col, tf.negative(pad_col)], axis=1)
      pad_row = tf.concat([pad_row, tf.negative(pad_row)], axis=1)
      #tile padding 4D
      pad_col = tf.reshape(pad_col, [1,pad_col_size,1,2])
      pad_row = tf.reshape(pad_row, [1,1,pad_row_size,2])
      #tile padding down two channels
      pad_col = tf.tile(pad_col, [2,1,1,int(num_channels/2)])
      pad_row = tf.tile(pad_row, [2,1,1,int(num_channels/2)])
  elif num_channels==3:
      #tile padding 2D
      pad_col = tf.concat([pad_col, tf.negative(pad_col), pad_col], axis=1)
      pad_row = tf.concat([pad_row, tf.negative(pad_row), pad_row], axis=1)
      #tile padding 4D
      pad_col = tf.reshape(pad_col, [1,pad_col_size,1,num_channels])
      pad_row = tf.reshape(pad_row, [1,1,pad_row_size,num_channels])
      #tile padding down two channels
      pad_col = tf.concat([pad_col, tf.negative(pad_col)], axis=0)
      pad_row = tf.concat([pad_row, tf.negative(pad_row)], axis=0)
  elif num_channels==1:
      #tile padding 4D
      pad_col = tf.reshape(pad_col, [1,pad_col_size,1,num_channels])
      pad_row = tf.reshape(pad_row, [1,1,pad_row_size,num_channels])
      #tile padding down two channels
      pad_col = tf.concat([pad_col, tf.negative(pad_col)], axis=0)
      pad_row = tf.concat([pad_row, tf.negative(pad_row)], axis=0)
  else:
    print('This OddEvenPad function only supports channel lengths = 1, 3, 2*(any int)')

  #tile down batch
  pad_col = tf.tile(pad_col, [int(num_batch/2),1,1,1])
  pad_row = tf.tile(pad_row, [int(num_batch/2),1,1,1])

  #add column padding to tensor
  padding_X = tf.concat([pad_col, X], axis=2)
  padding_X = tf.concat([padding_X, tf.negative(pad_col)], axis=2)

  #add row padding to tensor
  padding_X = tf.concat([pad_row, padding_X], axis=1)
  padded_X = tf.concat([padding_X, tf.negative(pad_row)], axis=1)

  return padded_X
```